# Recuperar lista encadeada de arquivo.bin

Tags: c, arquivo, lista, lista-encadeada

Estou programando em C e tenho um código que utiliza uma lista sequencial de 50 posições para guardar em cada um de seus espaços o primeiro endereço de varias listas encadeadas, até ai tudo bem, o problema é quando preencho a lista e gravo em um arquivo.bin, pois na hora de realizar a recuperação dos dados do arquivo para o software, consigo apenas o conteúdo das listas sequenciais já o das listas encadeadas são perdidos, acredito que seja porque no momento em que faço a recuperação dos dados, os endereços antigos que eram ocupados pelas listas encadeadas já não estão disponíveis na mesma sequencia em que estavam no momento em que gravei o arquivo, alguém poderia me confirmar se é realmente esse o problema e se há alguma solução?

Comment: Como você serializou a lista encadeada para dentro do arquivo?

Comment: Fiz usando a função fwrite() da seguinte forma:
    fwrite(lista, sizeof(struct), 1, fp);

Comment: Eu acho que você acabou editando e perdendo o comentário anterior. Eu me lembro de ter visto um `fwrite` passando a estrutura e o tamanho dela. Isso vai causar perda de informação e impossibilidade de remontar a estrutura novamente. Você precisa serializar sem perder informação

Comment: No caso não deveria ser usado o fwrite()?

Comment: Deveria ser com `fwrite`, mas não ingenuamente.

Comment: Nesse caso o problema seria resolvido manualmente através de algum método de acrescentar informações que seriam arquivadas juntamente com os dados no arquivo.bin?